# Fresh install of Apache Directory Studio in macOS fails to start a new LDAP server

Tags: apache-directory

I installed Apache Directory Studio version 2.0.0-M17 via this [official download link](https://directory.apache.org/studio/download/download-macosx.html). I launched the software from Launchpad and created a new LDAP server.

However, when I try to start the server, the status changes quickly from *Starting* to *Stopped*, and no logs are displayed. How can I debug the problem?

I tried to modify the `ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini` and uncommented the following lines to config the heap memory:

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx2g
```

I relaunched the Eclipse-based studio software, but the situation is the same.

Here are the `apacheds.log`:

```
[17:34:12] INFO [org.apache.directory.server.UberjarMain] - Starting the service.
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.841' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.2' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.528' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[17:34:14] WARN [org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService] - You didn't change the admin password of directory service instance 'default'.  Please update the admin password as soon as possible to prevent a possible security breach.
[09:32:44] INFO [org.apache.directory.server.UberjarMain] - Starting the service.
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.841' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.2' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:46] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.528' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[09:32:47] WARN [org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService] - You didn't change the admin password of directory service instance 'default'.  Please update the admin password as soon as possible to prevent a possible security breach.
```

Operating System: macOS 10.15.7

[image: empty logs]

Comment: I am having the exact same problem here. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I've tried to run it in both type of macs(m1 / intel)

Comment: No. I still don't have luck. I end up using a Docker container to work on my project. Use the ADS as a client only.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but same thing happened to me March 2023 with a new install of Studio on a new Win 11 machine, and the latest (and recommended) Eclipse Temurin JDK 17. A bunch of MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL messages.

I read an article suggesting going back to JDK 11. I uninstalled JDK 17, installed JDK 11 and it worked first go.

https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=11 is the link to the JDK that worked for me.

Comment: I just want to add that after install the JDK 11, you don't have to uninstall any newer version.


You can go to `/Applications/ApacheDirectoryStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini` file to uncomment `#-vm`, then add the JDK 11 java path, for example: 
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`. 


Check https://directory.apache.org/studio/faqs.html#how-to-set-the-java-vm-to-use